# Hex editor for large files in Linux

Tags: linux, hex-editor

I need to edit and navigate through a rather large binary file (~8 GB) in Linux. I'd use [Hiew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiew) if I was on Windows, are there any similar tools for Linux?

Preferably GNOME applications, but terminal ones will do as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using [Curses Hexedit](http://www.rogoyski.com/adam/programs/hexedit/onlinedoc/hexedit.html), it doesn't seem to care of the filesizes and I have often edited even my harddisks directly with it.

Comment: Link rot of the downloads on that page

Comment: When exporting large disk segments into file, Hexedit only exports up to 280MB. Compared to that small limit the 2GiB of wxHexEdit (see below) seem big.

Answer (score 14):

**[wxHexEditor](http://wxhexeditor.sf.net)**

There is no good hex/disk editor for linux. So I build one for myself...
It's open source and can open files up to "exabyte".

[image]

Comment: +1 Since you contribute back to the community, GPL:ed app hosted on SourceForge :)

Comment: +1, The blog post comparing `5 Unix editors` also lists `wxHexEditor` along with `LFHex`. `Community++ :-)` Keep up the good work!

Comment: Not HiDPI compatible, very slow (even on a 10M file), missing simple options like fixed columns and insert cursor, and lots of typos

Comment: Although wxHexEditor can open a huge disk directly, it can only dump segments up to 2GiB into a single file… (using v0.24).

Comment: +1. If you want something done well, do it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Check the Linux column at this [Comparison of hex editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors).
And a [Comparison of 5 Hex Editors for Ubuntu](http://unixlab.blogspot.com/2009/08/five-gui-hex-editors-for-ubuntu.html).
Refers [LFHex](http://stoopidsimple.com/),

> lfhex can view files over 4gigs in size (if the OS supports large file offsets). Using a paged i/o abstraction file open times are invariant with file size, a 2gig file opens just as fast as a 2k file.

Comment: I tried lfhex, but it  seems to be lacking even a simple search function.

Comment: there are more editors in the other two links.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried an 8GB file, but vim has always worked for me `:%!xxd` converts to hex, `:%!xxd -r` converts back.  I've also used okteta, but it's a KDE app.  Check out [this page](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/36901.aspx).

Comment: Note that vim sometimes converts binary files while opening the buffer (indicated with `[converted]`), causing the buffer to be bigger than the file (because of inserted characters), and thus the corruption of said file if you over-write it. Even with `:set binary`. Even if you don't even touch anything and just do `$ vim "+set binary" <file> +wq`. In my experiment, the file became 150% larger regardless of what I did. Rather, what you want to do is not let vim handle the binary *at all* and delegate it entirely to xxd and the shell: `:r !xxd <file>` to read and `:w !xxd -r > <file>` to write.

Answer (score 1):

there is [bview](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/view/doc/bview.1.html) that **may** do that

Answer (score 0):

Art: lfview does have a search function, counter-intuitively called "Conversion Assistant" in the "View" menu. That function converts ascii to hex, for example, and searches for the result.

lfview can handle files larger than RAM, while bvi/bview is limited by available memory.

Comment: bvi (version 1.3.2-2) on my Ubuntu Precise on amd64 actually does not work properly with files larger than 2G (actually 4K smaller than that): although it correctly recognizes the length of file, everything starting from the offset `0x7ffff000` is shown as `00`s.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently I published Hexinator, a free hex editor for Linux: https://hexinator.com

It supports many text encodings, shows variables of different sizes and much more.

[image: Hexinator screen shot]